# How to handle variable containing parentheses in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script to get the name of a file/directory which is getting right-clicked, modify it and put the modified string on the clipboard.

This works nicely as long as the string does not contain parentheses. If so, I am getting an error when trying to do anything with it. E.g. if $args contains "C:\Document(draft).pdf" and I'm trying to echo it using

```
Write-Host $args
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The term 'draft' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

How to handle variables containing parentheses in such a case?

Comment: can you post your whole script?

Comment: For simplicity sake, let's say that's the whole script, simply echoing the command line argument, which will be the name of whatever file the user right-clicked on. This will not work if it contains parentheses. How can I solve this?

Comment: Im still not able to reproduce that thus can't help you if you dont post your code.

Comment: I'm not sure how can I make it any clearer: the code is a very simple one-liner: 
'Write-Host $args'
Variable $args (command-line argument supplied when the script is called) is "C:\Document(draft).pdf" or any other file the user is specifying. In case it has parentheses, an error will occur. How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score -1):

Use single quoatation marks. This code works:

```
$args = 'c:\document(draft).pdf'

if ($args -contains 'C:\Document(draft).pdf')
{
Write-Host $args
}
```

Output:

```
c:\document(draft).pdf
```

Comment: That is not going to work, because the file name is not known, it can be any file name, which is being right-clicked on.

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more code? In my environment this is working. Which PS version are you using?

Comment: I'm using PS v5 (Win10). It really doesn't need more code. I simply want to  echo the command line argument, which can be any filename, which may contain parentheses.